# 2 Functions have to be true to submit the form. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

So the two Functions (chForumular() and validate_user_text()) have both to be true to submit the form. Right now you cant send the form without fil in the username, age(in the code Alter) and your E-Mail. but the second function (validate_user_text) should check if there is any swear word in the message (=Nachricht) right know it submits the form after you fil in the three fields (e-mail, name and age). iven if you type in an swearword in the textarea. (something like: sorry ((asshole)))

If you dont understand a Word you think could be important just write the word to me so I can translate...(German and Swissgerman Words in the Code)

Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kontakt.css" media="screen">
<title>Kontaktseite</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
function chkFormular () {
  if (document.Formular.User.value == "") {
    alert("Enter your Name, Please!");
    document.Formular.User.focus();
    return false;
  }
 // if (document.Formular.Ort.value == "") {
 //   alert("Bitte Ihren Wohnort eingeben!");
  //  document.Formular.Ort.focus();
   // return false;
 // }
  if (document.Formular.Mail.value == "") {
    alert("Enter your E-Mail, please!");
    document.Formular.Mail.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.Formular.Mail.value.indexOf("@") == -1) {
    alert("No valid E-Mail, address!");
    document.Formular.Mail.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.Formular.Alter.value == "") {
    alert("Enter your Age, please!");
    document.Formular.Alter.focus();
    return false;
  }
  var chkZ = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < document.Formular.Alter.value.length; ++i)
    if (document.Formular.Alter.value.charAt(i) < "0" ||
        document.Formular.Alter.value.charAt(i) > "9")
      chkZ = -1;
  if (chkZ == -1) {
    alert("Your Age is not a Number!");
    document.Formular.Alter.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
</script>

<script language="JavaScript1.2">

// Word Filter
// (c) 2002 Premshree Pillai
// http://www.qiksearch.com
// http://javascript.qik.cjb.net

var swear_words_arr=new Array("arschloch","idiot","terror", "wixer", "wixxer", "hure", "hurensohn", "hurenson", "motherfucker", "neger", "sauhund", "arsch", "fuck", "fucking", "shit", "satan",
"satanus", "figge", "ficken", "scheiss", "drecksjude", "drecksjud", "i hoff du stirbsch", "geh sterben", "verrecken", "verreck doch", "chrüppel", "krüppel", "chrüpel", "krüpel", "saftsack",
"sackratte", "god damit", "goddamit", "godvertammi", "gopfetammi", "chrüzsatan", "gottvertammi", "gottpfertami", "gopfeteckel", "verflucht", "verfluecht", "damisiech", "ich hoffe du stirbst",
"stirb", "geh sterben", "ass", "asshole", "cunt"); //corrected commas
var swear_alert_arr=new Array;
var swear_alert_count=0;

function reset_alert_count()
{
 swear_alert_count=0;
}

function validate_user_text()
{
 reset_alert_count();
 var compare_text=document.Formular.user_text.value;
 for(var i=0; i<swear_words_arr.length; i++)
 {
  for(var j=0; j<(compare_text.length); j++)
  {
   if(swear_words_arr[i]==compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase())
   {
    swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count]=compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length));
    swear_alert_count++;
   }
  }
 }
 var alert_text="";
 for(var k=1; k<=swear_alert_count; k++)
 {
  alert_text+="\n" + "(" + k + ")  " + swear_alert_arr[k-1];
 }
 if(swear_alert_count>0)
 {
  alert("The following Words are not allwoed:\n_______________________________\n" + alert_text + "\n_______________________________");
  document.Formular.user_text.select();
 }
 else
 {
  document.Formular.submit();
 }
}

function select_area()
{
 document.Formular.user_text.select();
}

window.onload=reset_alert_count;

</script>


</head>
<body>

<h1>Kontaktformular</h1>

<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="mistica.html" class="siesindhier">Zurück</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="part1">
<form name="Formular" action="http://www.formular-chef.de/fc.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onSubmit="return chkFormular()">
<input type="hidden" name="empfaenger" value="benjamin.laubeX§Xbrueggli.ch">
<!--<input type="hidden" name="empfaenger" value="dominik.widmerX§Xbrueggli.ch">--> 
 </div>
 <div id="part2">
<pre>
Name:    &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" size="40" name="User"><br>
E-Mail:  &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" size="40" name="Mail"><br>
Alter:   &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" size="40" name="Alter"><br>

Geschlecht: <select name="geschlecht">
                <option selected>-</option>
                <option>männlich</option>
                <option>weiblich</option>
            </select>
</div>

<p id="nachricht">Deine Nachricht:</p> 
<div id="part3">
<textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="user_text" onclick="select_area()" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht..."></textarea>
</div>
<div id="part4">
Zum Absenden muss eine Internet-Verbindung bestehen!
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Absenden" onclick="validate_user_text();"><input type="reset" value="Abbrechen">

</div>
</pre>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which era are you in, using `JavaScript1.2`?

Comment: well its old...but I could not find any newer usable example code...it works fine in use without the other Function...

Comment: released in 1997 to be exact lol

Comment: `swear_words_arr` has to be in contention for the most exciting array contents on this site.

Comment: There's a lot of words going to be missing from any defined array of swear words/insults. And people always find ways round such arbitrary restrictions by using different letters, adding hyphens, etc. And it's also prone to disallow perfectly valid words also, such as bastard or ass, which are not necessarily "swearing" at all. Great array though. You've taught me some great new insults! :-p

Comment: haha well most of the swarwords i have in there are Swissgerman...we dont have many customers who speak english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kontakt.css" media="screen">
<title>Kontaktseite</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
function chkFormular () {
  if (document.Formular.User.value == "") {
    alert("Enter your Name, Please!");
    document.Formular.User.focus();
    return false;
  }
 // if (document.Formular.Ort.value == "") {
 //   alert("Bitte Ihren Wohnort eingeben!");
  //  document.Formular.Ort.focus();
   // return false;
 // }
  if (document.Formular.Mail.value == "") {
    alert("Enter your E-Mail, please!");
    document.Formular.Mail.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.Formular.Mail.value.indexOf("@") == -1) {
    alert("No valid E-Mail, address!");
    document.Formular.Mail.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.Formular.Alter.value == "") {
    alert("Enter your Age, please!");
    document.Formular.Alter.focus();
    return false;
  }
  var chkZ = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < document.Formular.Alter.value.length; ++i)
    if (document.Formular.Alter.value.charAt(i) < "0" ||
        document.Formular.Alter.value.charAt(i) > "9")
      chkZ = -1;
  if (chkZ == -1) {
    alert("Your Age is not a Number!");
    document.Formular.Alter.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</script>

<script language="JavaScript1.2">

// Word Filter
// (c) 2002 Premshree Pillai
// http://www.qiksearch.com
// http://javascript.qik.cjb.net

var swear_words_arr=new Array("arschloch","idiot","terror", "wixer", "wixxer", "hure", "hurensohn", "hurenson", "motherfucker", "neger", "sauhund", "arsch", "fuck", "fucking", "shit", "satan",
"satanus", "figge", "ficken", "scheiss", "drecksjude", "drecksjud", "i hoff du stirbsch", "geh sterben", "verrecken", "verreck doch", "chrüppel", "krüppel", "chrüpel", "krüpel", "saftsack",
"sackratte", "god damit", "goddamit", "godvertammi", "gopfetammi", "chrüzsatan", "gottvertammi", "gottpfertami", "gopfeteckel", "verflucht", "verfluecht", "damisiech", "ich hoffe du stirbst",
"stirb", "geh sterben", "ass", "asshole", "cunt");
var swear_alert_arr=new Array;
var swear_alert_count=0;

function reset_alert_count()
{
 swear_alert_count=0;
}

function validate_user_text()
{
 reset_alert_count();
 var compare_text=document.Formular.user_text.value;
 for(var i=0; i<swear_words_arr.length; i++)
 {
  for(var j=0; j<(compare_text.length); j++)
  {
   if(swear_words_arr[i]==compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase())
   {
    swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count]=compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length));
    swear_alert_count++;
   }
  }
 }
 var alert_text="";
 for(var k=1; k<=swear_alert_count; k++)
 {
  alert_text+="\n" + "(" + k + ")  " + swear_alert_arr[k-1];
 }
 if(swear_alert_count>0)
 {
  alert("The following Words are not allwoed:\n_______________________________\n" + alert_text + "\n_______________________________");
  document.Formular.user_text.select();
 }
 else
 {
     return true;
 }
}

function select_area()
{
 document.Formular.user_text.select();
}

window.onload=reset_alert_count;

</script>


</head>
<body>

<h1>Kontaktformular</h1>

<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="mistica.html" class="siesindhier">Zurück</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>




<div id="part1">
<form id="frmFormular" name="Formular" action="http://www.formular-chef.de/fc.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="empfaenger" value="benjamin.laubeX§Xbrueggli.ch">
<!--<input type="hidden" name="empfaenger" value="dominik.widmerX§Xbrueggli.ch">--> 
 </div>
 <div id="part2">
<pre>
Name:    &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" size="40" name="User"><br>
E-Mail:  &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" size="40" name="Mail"><br>
Alter:   &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" size="40" name="Alter"><br>

Geschlecht: <select name="geschlecht">
                <option selected>-</option>
                <option>männlich</option>
                <option>weiblich</option>
            </select>
</div>

<p id="nachricht">Deine Nachricht:</p> 
<div id="part3">
<textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="user_text" onclick="select_area()" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht..."></textarea>
</div>
<div id="part4">
Zum Absenden muss eine Internet-Verbindung bestehen!
<br><br>

<input type="submit" id="sendButton" value="Absenden">
<input type="reset" value="Abbrechen">

<script>
document.getElementById('sendButton').onclick = function() {
    if (chkFormular() && validate_user_text()) {
         document.formular.submit();
         return true;
    } else {

         return false;
    }

}
</script>    

</div>
</pre>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmm it doesent work for me...it submits the form with or without swearwords/fields filled...

Comment: Ok, did you put commas in swear word array in right places? If yes then try this (changing input and script tags places):

    <input type="submit" id="sendButton" value="Absenden">
    <script>
    document.getElementById('sendButton').onclick = function() {
    if (chForumular() && validate_user_text()) {
         return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }

    }
    </script>

Comment: I did...
doesent work either... Is there a way to run both functions with the onClick="" attribute for the input?

Comment: Yes, Nina's answer does that: onSubmit="return (chkFormular() && validate_user_text())" or try onClick="return (chkFormular() && validate_user_text())" You can also try putting onsubmit to the form.

Comment: If i put onClick="return (chkFormular() && validate_user_text())" then the chkFormular() function works...but the validate_user_text() doesent...

Comment: So the difference from initial code is that form.onSubmit removed from chkFormular and onsubmit removed from form. Your problem was bad syntax in swear words array and submit is initiated in multiple places, so even if one event is stoping submit - the others just go through.

Comment: Wait a second...it works with the functions now...but the form does not submit if nothing is wrong with it...?

Comment: In that onclick function before return true add: document.Formular.submit();

Comment: Check the edited code - it submits, but I get this: SPAM-FILTER, Eintrag abgelehnt / Access denied. Only one function was actually returning true...the other does not return anything even if it's ok.

Comment: I check it...at least you get something back :) I can klick the submit button as much as I want to...nothing happens...

Comment: Well thank you for your Help adomas, it works now...just had to add an return true on the validate_user_text function :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the submit part.

```
onSubmit="return chkFormular() && validate_user_text()"
```

Comment: If I do that it gives me the response that I have to Enter my Name, but the swearword-filter gets ignorred...